# OSX - Can't configure rgdal for install

Tags: r, macos, rgdal, proj

So I've been through a few problems trying to install rgdal. I'm running OS X 10.10.4

First I tried installing it from R :

```
install.packages("rgdal")
```

but the config file was not found :

```
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
```

So I installed gdal using Homebrew :

```
brew install gdal
```

Which installed a few dependencies alongside, like proj.

Problem is, R still can't install rgdal :

```
configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations.
```

So I tried installing it manually, copying the `rgdal_1.0-7.tar.gz` from the temporary downloaded sources and unzipping it.
As `./config` still seemed to fail finding `proj_api.h`, I searched it on my computer and found out it was in `/usr/local/Cellar/proj/4.9.1/include`, I tried

```
./configure CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/Cellar/proj/4.9.1/include"
```

... but it still doesn't work.

Now `configure` finds `proj_api.h`, but seems to be unable to find the functions defined in this header :

```
checking for proj_api.h... yes
checking for pj_init_plus in -lproj... no
configure: error: libproj not found in standard or given locations.
```

So now I don't know what to do anymore.

Any help would be great :)

Comment: Have you read the note about installing on OSX in the "System Requirements" section on the package's [CRAN-hosted splash page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html)?

Comment: For some reason, I thought I had installed the framework but I didn't... so now I've installed it and it actually made things worse : the `./configure` now stops sooner with error :
    `checking gdal: linking with --libs only... no`
    `checking gdal: linking with --libs and --dep-libs... no`
    `ld: framework not found GDAL`

Comment: I use homebrew vs other installers for `gdal` etc and I can do `brew install gdal` and then do an `rgdal` package install (from source) w/o incident but I'm also on Yosemite or El Capitan.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Wish I could be of more help, but I'm a Windows user. So @hrbrmstr will be way more helpful than me. (If you don't get help here, I might suggest trying the [R-sig-geo mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-geo) (of course after doing your due diligence to see whether this has already been resolved in other discussions over there).)

Comment: I'll try to fire up a vanilla Yosemite VM in a bit and go through the steps and paste them into an answer box.

Comment: Tried the way hrbrmstr suggested and it worked for me.